# After input in text box how do cause AfterUpdate event to run?

Tags: excel, vba, textbox

I have an Excel VBA userform with several text boxes.
The user will input a weight in a text box. They can then do other things on the form or click Apply, Update, Previous Event, Next Event or Cancel.

After the weight is input, it must be validated, and if it is OK, the form is marked as `mbFormChanged=True`.  This validation occurs in the text box's AfterUpdate event.

My problem is that if the user types in a value and immediately clicks Apply, Update, Previous Event or Next Event, the field is not validated and it is as if it was never changed.

I.e enter weight:    200[Update]

However, if the user tabs to another field after typing the weight, then it is validated and the form is marked as changed.

I.e. enter weight:   200[Tab][Update]

How can I make sure AfterUpdate runs when a command button is clicked immediately thereafter?

I can't put the validation at the point of OK/Apply because the moment a user enters a new weight and it is valid, it immediately updates many other fields and lists visible on the form (real time update).

Comment: Add a Change_Event which will prompt the user (using MsgBox) if he's done entering the weight. If He press ok, then pass the focus using *SetFocus* property to other controls.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an Excel user form in which case I don't think there is a built in `AfterUpdate` event. Excel forms are not bound to anything (unlike Access) so there is nothing the *form* updates. You'll need to make your own `AfterUpdate` event.

Comment: Yes, Excel. There is a built in AfterUpdate event for all text boxes. Mine is called txtNewWeight_AfterUpdate() in which I have placed my validation script.  I just don't know how to make it kick off when the user presses a command button right after typing in a new value.

Comment: Your after update fires when you leave the textbox. by the time a user has clicked a button the after update has come and gone. Can you not just call the validation code from your button click since that's when you want it to happen?

Comment: Thanks, but I need to validation to be immediate because in addition to validation, may other related fields are immediately updated before the final OK/Apply is clicked. (Updated my question to say this.)

Comment: @ShariW well if the user clicks OK and validation fails you should not be proceeding with your update. You can either validate the textbox when it loses focus (normal AfterUpdate event) or validate the form on your submit button click.

Comment: Let's think about what you're saying here `I can't put the validation at the point of OK/Apply because the moment a user enters a new weight and it is valid [do stuff]` you say this is the place to do it right here: `and it is valid` i.e. passes validation. Click -> validate -> if valid Update your stuff, if not valid call out what is invalid and do no update.

Comment: I am not sure what you are suggesting here.  Imagine I have a weight input field for bananas. User inputs 3 lbs bananas. Tab key will kick off AfterUpdate which validates the number and updates other text boxes. The "total grocery weight" box goes from 8 to 11. The "total fruits ordered" box goes from 2 to 5. The "total banana inventory" goes from 20 to 17.  The use sees all this and it looks good, so they continue ordering or they press OK to save all the data. My problem: If they type in 3 lbs and directly click Update, their input is lost. Thanks for talking this out with me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a an old/dead thread and I certainly hope the original problem has been solved, but in case anyone else is searching this, here is what I have done in similar situations:  Open your form with the 'Ok' / 'Done' / 'Exit" or whatever button(s) you are using to confirm the form entries then exit the form in a disabled state.  That way they do nothing if clicked on.  Once your data validation is complete, enable those buttons (or circle back for corrected entries).

Answer (score -1):

As commented, you can try this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    If (MsgBox("Done?", vbYesNo)) = vbYes Then Me.TextBox2.SetFocus 'Or any other ctrl
End Sub
```

Above code like forces *TextBox1_AfterUpdate()* event.

Comment: Thanks. This would work for some apps and input types, but not for mine. It checks for done after every character input. So if I have to type in 75.3, the question would come up four times. Even one time is too much. I need it to detect when the cursor leaves that box (?)